# adobe air development ide / tools

Tags: air, adobe, aptana3

I would like build html5 apps for desktop in Adobe Air. Unfortunately the Aptana studio 3 doesn't support Adobe air I think, only the Aptana studio 2.

So what is the best development ide for Adobe air?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so I think the Adobe Air platform is dead, but I found the [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/) which allows you development native desktop apps in HTML5/css3/js

I think, this is one of the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Flashdevelop is best IDE for developing actionscript based project. 
It is free, lightweighted.
Has lots of helpers bat files for build process.
Also building adobe air projects with actionscript runs faster than html/js based hybrid applications that runs on browser.